# MYSQL - another optimize sql

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I've done the following sql query, it picks data from some tables and try to infere the right coincidence. As you can see the query is huge, and time is not so bad (I've done the same with php code getting 15s to process 2000 database results, and now with mysql takes "only" 0.6s).
Can you tell me some basic optimization guidelines some obvious failiures and non sense parts?
Note: query is working fine (I think for now).

This is the query:

[Query result][1]

```
SELECT COUNT(dbpaymentref) AS cnt1, facf.`ref` AS factureref, facf.`total_ttc` AS factureamount, llx_paiementfourn.`amount` AS dbamount, llx_paiementfourn.`amount` AS amount2, date1, id, `import`, manualpayment, dbpaymentref, details, alias
FROM (
  SELECT T05.`date1`, T05.`id`, T05.`import`, T05.`manualpayment`, T05.`dbpaymentref`, T05.`details`, T06.`alias`
    FROM(
      SELECT T3.`date1`, T3.`id`, T3.`import`, T3.`manualpayment` AS manualpayment, 
      T3.`dbpaymentref` AS dbpaymentref, T3.`details` 
      FROM (
        SELECT T2.`date1`, T2.`id`, T2.`import`, T2.`paymentref` AS manualpayment, T2.`ref` AS 
        dbpaymentref, T2.`details` 
        FROM(
          SELECT DATE_FORMAT(llx_csvbank.date1, '%d/%m/%Y')AS date1, llx_csvbank.`id`, 
          llx_csvbank.`import`, llx_csvbank.`paymentref`, T1.`ref`, llx_csvbank.`details` 
          FROM 
            llx_csvbank
            LEFT JOIN llx_paiementfourn AS T1 ON 
              (((
              T1.`amount`=(llx_csvbank.import*-1) 
              AND ABS(DATE_FORMAT(T1.datec, '%Y%m%d')-DATE_FORMAT(llx_csvbank.date1, '%Y%m%d'))<2 
              AND T1.`ref`<>llx_csvbank.`paymentref` 
              AND LENGTH(llx_csvbank.`paymentref`)<2) ) 
              OR T1.`ref`=llx_csvbank.`paymentref` )
          ) AS T2
          LEFT JOIN llx_csvbank ON llx_csvbank.`paymentref`=T2.ref
          WHERE llx_csvbank.`paymentref` IS NULL 
          ORDER BY T2.id
       ) AS T3 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT * 
       FROM (
         SELECT DATE_FORMAT(T03.date1, '%d/%m/%Y')AS date1, T03.`id`, T03.`import`, 
         T03.`paymentref` AS manualpayment, T1.`ref` AS dbpaymentref, T03.`details` 
         FROM 
           llx_csvbank AS T03
         RIGHT JOIN llx_paiementfourn AS T1 ON 
         (
        T1.`ref`=T03.`paymentref` 
         )
         WHERE LENGTH(T03.`paymentref`)>2 AND T03.`date1` IS NOT NULL
         ORDER BY T03.`id`
       ) AS T04
    ) AS T05
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT llx_csv2alias.`alias`, llx_csv2alias.`id`, llx_csv2alias.`ocurrence` 
    FROM llx_csv2alias
    GROUP BY llx_csv2alias.`alias`
    ) 
    AS T06 ON 
    (LOCATE(T06.ocurrence, T05.details)>0) 
    ORDER BY T05.`id` , T06.`alias`
    ) AS T07
    LEFT JOIN llx_paiementfourn ON llx_paiementfourn.`ref`=T07.`dbpaymentref`
    LEFT JOIN llx_paiementfourn_facturefourn AS pai2fac ON 
    pai2fac.fk_paiementfourn=llx_paiementfourn.rowid
    LEFT JOIN llx_facture_fourn AS facf ON pai2fac.`fk_facturefourn`=facf.`rowid` 
    GROUP BY id
;
```

Output of EXPLAIN option: [EXPLAIN option][1]

Edit:
-Added EXPLAIN option 
-My client (sqlyog) seems not supporting \G, gives me error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZQWS.jpg

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. When asking SQL optimization questions, it's always helpful to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the tables referenced in your query, and include the result in your query as text, in case any readers want to test your query. Also useful is to include the output of `EXPLAIN` for your query to show how it is currently using indexes. Best if you run with the `\G` formatting option in the MySQL client to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug.  You cannot subtract dates this way; see the `DATEDIFF()` function; it might work for you:

```
AND  ABS(DATE_FORMAT(T1.datec, '%Y%m%d') -
         DATE_FORMAT(llx_csvbank.date1, '%Y%m%d'))
```

I hope `datec` is of datatype `DATE` or `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.  In which case, `DATE_FORMAT()` may be unnecessary.

It *may* be better to say `AND some_date >= other_date - INTERVAL 2 DAY`

Some of these composite indexes may help:

```
facf:  INDEX(rowid,  ref, total_ttc)
llx_paiementfourn:  INDEX(ref,  amount, rowid)
T07:  INDEX(dbpaymentref)
pai2fac:  INDEX(fk_paiementfourn,  fk_facturefourn)
llx_csvbank:  INDEX(import,  date1, id, paymentref, details)
T2:  INDEX(ref, id,  date1, import, paymentref, details)
llx_csvbank:  INDEX(paymentref,  date1, id, import, details)
T03:  INDEX(paymentref, date1, id,  import, details)
T1:  INDEX(ref)
llx_csv2alias:  INDEX(alias,  id, ocurrence)
T05:  INDEX(details,  date1, id, import, manualpayment, dbpaymentref)
T06:  INDEX(ocurrence,  alias)
```